# Does « Jake rappelle ‘qch’ » mean “Jake recalls ‘something’ ? By recall I mean “Jake brings ‘something’ to mind” and ‘something’ is any noun

Tags: constructions

I saw the sentence

« Le président rappelle l'importance des gestes barrières ». The translation that came with it is
“The president recalls the importance of barrier gestures”. I don’t know if the translation is correct because I saw this pair of sentences on a forum but **if it is**, I would like to ask the question

does « Jake rappelle **qch** » mean “Jake *recalls* **something**” ? By *recall* I mean “Jake brings **something** to mind and also this **something** is any noun.

Btw, my level is beginner so if you are going give an explanation, please make it as simple as you can. Thank you!!! :)

Answer (score 5):

***[Rappeler](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rappeler)*** does mean ***<s>recall</s>*** / ***bring something to someone else's mind*** here. It can have other meanings depending on the context, like *to call back*.

Here are some common usages:

> *Rappeler quelque chose (**à** quelqu'un)* → To remind sth (to someone)
> *Rappeler quelqu'un* → To call back someone
> *Rappeler quelqu'un à l'ordre* → To call someone to order
> ***Se** rappeler (de) quelque chose* → To remember something
> ***Se** rappeler (de) quelqu'un* → To remember someone

Comment: Isn't "Recall" = "Se rappeler" when it comes to thinking?

Comment: @LaurentS.Indeed, I mixed up meanings. Thanks.

Comment: @jiliagre So, just to confirm: (1) « Jake rappelle **qch** » means “Jake is bringing **sth** to *sb else*’s mind” but that *sb else* isn’t mentioned. It’s just implied that *THAT SB* is there. (2) « Jake se rappelle qch » means « Jake is bringing **sth** to his own mind. Is this correct?

Comment: @CubbyKushi Yes to both. In that sentence, the persons for whom the message is intended are not mentioned. *Se rappeler (de) quelque chose* is close to *se souvenir de quelque chose* and means *to remember something*

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @jiliagre ! :)

Answer (score 4):

No, that is not the meaning of "rappeler" here. The meaning is "to remind". As "to remind" is transitive an object must be added.

- The president reminded everyone of the importance of barrier gestures.

Comment: The following is off-topic, as you have, imo, correctly identified the pertinent notion: "to remind" but mightn't the present tense of *rappeler* in the French version be better translated w/the present continuous than w/the past in English? "The president IS REMINDING [us] of the importance of barrier gestures (protective measures). The simple present of *remind* would be weird here (w/out adding something like "reminds us DAILY") but it works if the message was changed to "That president reminds us of a pear-shaped orange" (hopefully the past tense will soon be appropriate for that version).

Comment: @PapaPoule **1/** I don't think the present would be so weird at face value but I need some reassurance and, apparently, I get it from ACGOTEL (Quirk et al); here is what this reference tells us. A very different use of the present tense in reference to the past [i.e. different from the usual historic present] is that found with verbs of communication [and "remind" is such a verb I believe]: ex. The ten o'clock news says that there is going to be a bad storm. Martin tells me the Smiths are moving from N° 20. [it goes on] Such verbs include  (1/5)

Comment: @Papaoule also verbs like "understand", "hear" and "learn", which refer to the receptive end of the communication process: ex.I hear that poor Mr Simpson has gone into  hospital. [Moreover what's next  answers another part of your  question] These sentences [the ex. given] would also be acceptable with the simple past or present perfective; but the implication of the present tense seems to be that although the communication event took place in the past, its result--the information communicated--is still operative. (2/5)

Comment: @PapaPoule **2/** In reference to your remark that "reminds us DAILY" is effective [this is the habitual present], I think I can add something worth considering: because of this special possibility of referring to the past by means of the present for verbs of communication, there is a possible overlap with the use of the same present tense in the habitual present; however, ACGOTEL tells us that "[i]t is a sign of the habitual present that one can easily add a frequency adverbial to specify the frequency of the repetition.". I can now add this: "With verbs of communication,(3/5)

Comment: @Papaoule this addition becomes a way to resolve the ambiguity. (continuously, often, etc.)". **3/** As regard your main claim [the continuous present being preferable] I again find the possibility quite natural; it seems to me it could be used and that the main characteristic of that aspect--the continuation into the present--is tantamount to the idea of the communication being operative at the present moment when the simple present is used with verbs of communication for events in the past. However, I get no back up for that. **4/**  We can say that the last sentence is effective  (4/5)

Comment: @PapaPoule  because we recognize the state present (facts that are true over an indefinite period of time).**5/**  One last point: you qualify "barrier gestures" in a parenthesis; what's that drawback you seem to be conscious of? I didn't question the term and if I  do not hold the French counterpart as very good language I have as yet no opinion about the English one. (5/5)